# crontab cannot run shell script with docker command?

Tags: docker, shell, cron

I have a simple shell script to run a docker command below, which works just fine if I ran it manually. However it didn't work if I ran it by cron. I didn't see any logging in `/var/log/cron`..
And I tested cron by creating a simple script to touch a file, and it worked fine. Cron doesn't work with docker?

```
cat start.sh
#!/bin/bash
docker run --shm-size 2g --rm --net sitespeedio_default \
    -v "$(pwd):/sitespeed.io" sitespeedio/sitespeed.io:24.6.0\
    --pageCompleteWaitTime 30000 \
    lex-login.js lex-view_call_call_only.js -n 1 \
    --influxdb.host influxdb \
    --influxdb.username $INFLUX_U \
    --influxdb.password $INFLUX_P --spa --multi

crontab -l
2 * * * * /home/ec2-user/start.sh >/dev/null 2>&1
```

Comment: The crontab(5) line explicitly suppresses the output from the command, which might be why you're not seeing anything come out.  Is the script executable?  Does your environment in fact have a `/bin/bash` (Alpine-based Docker images won't)?  Do you need to be root to run `docker` commands?

Comment: @DavidMaze I needed to make sure the user that runs the crontab has Docker in the path and what shell the crontab is using. It started working after SHELL and PATH were added to the crontab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update the `crontab` content to:

```
2 * * * *  /bin/bash /home/ec2-user/start.sh >/dev/null 2>&1
```

And then, make sure that the `crontab`'s user has the permission to run this script.